# Got stuck while changing data format from wide to long

Tags: r, reshape2, melt, mutate

I am a complete beginner in R. I installed R couple of days ago to complete my course assignment. One of the instructions was that I have to change the data format from wide to long format. The data was a time series data on Remittance inflows from 1972-2021 in Bangladesh. I had the years on the rows and amount of remittance from different countries in columns. I wrote the following code to change the data format to long format:

```
library(reshape2)
bd_remit_long <- melt(bd_remit,
                      id.vars = c("Saudi_Arabia", "U.A.E", "U.K", "Kuwait",
                                  "U.S.A", "Libya", "Qatar", "Oman", "Singapore",
                                  "Germany", "Bahrain", "Iran", "Japan"
                                  "Malaysia", "Australia", "Italy", "South_Korea"
                                  "Hong_Kong","Other_Countries", "Total"))
```

the country names mentioned here are in the columns in the initial data. After running the code my R console is showing: "Error: unexpected string constant in:
"                                  "Germany", "Bahrain", "Iran", "Japan"
"Malaysia""
I have went back to check my Excel file to see if there were any string values in the observations but couldn't find any. I have multiple missing values in several country observations which are denoted by "...". So to change those missing values to 'NA', I ran this code:

```
unique(bd_remit$Japan)
bd_remit %>%
  select(Japan,Malaysia,Australia,Italy,South_Korea,Hong_Kong)%>%
mutate(Japan = na_if (Japan, "..."))%>%
  mutate(Malaysia = na_if (Malaysia, "..."))%>%
  mutate(Australia = na_if (Australia, "..."))%>%
  mutate(Italy = na_if (Italy, "..."))%>%
  mutate(South_Korea = na_if (South_Korea, "..."))%>%
  mutate(Hong_Kong = na_if (Hong_Kong, "..."))%>%
```

(I have installed all the necessary packages to run these commands)
But the "..." values did not change into "NA" values either.
Now I am completely stuck and I don't know what to do. I really need to change the wide data into long data. Pls help me with your valuable suggestions

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO!
The code looks good already to me. All that I can spot now is that you left a whitespace after `na_if` which might introduce the malfunction.  
If you are using a function, the opening bracket has to come immediately after the function name. E.g.: `na_if(Japan, "...")`.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Thank you for your kind responses. I have deleted everything and reinstalled R, because I ran into further problems, I went on to create a new variable where the code ran successfully but the variable was not getting generated. I tried multiple times. Let's see if I have any luck this time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks you are missing a couple of commas when entering the string for the `id.vars` argument. Specifically, these are after `"Japan"` and `"South Korea"`. The following code should work.

```
library(reshape2)
bd_remit_long <- melt(bd_remit,
                      id.vars = c("Saudi_Arabia", "U.A.E", "U.K", "Kuwait",
                                  "U.S.A", "Libya", "Qatar", "Oman", "Singapore",
                                  "Germany", "Bahrain", "Iran", "Japan",
                                  "Malaysia", "Australia", "Italy", "South_Korea",
                                  "Hong_Kong","Other_Countries", "Total"))
```

Depending on how your data is formatted, you could also use the `tidyr` package to simplify the code. Assuming that these columns are in sequential order, the code would look something like this:

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(bd_remit, cols = Saudi_Arabia:Total)
```